# angular-ui-router dynamic menu: TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined while rendering menu

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

i am new to angular and angular-ui-router and trying to create a menu.
I tried angular-ui-router and think that it fits for my needs.
now i have a problem while creating the menu with the ui-router attributes.

my html code looks like that:

```
<div ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in menu">
            <a ui-sref="cf.{{item}}">{{item}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the menu array contains different entries dependent on the info if the user is logged in.

now i get this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined
<a ui-sref="cf.{{item}}" class="ng-binding">
```

It looks like ui-router tries to get access to the list entry before it is rendered complete with ng-repeat.

What can i do to prevent this problem?

Comment: `ui-sref="cf.{{item}}"` is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

So ui-router doesn't support interpolation in ui-sref, believe me I wish they would.  Here is how I solved this.

In your controller:

```
app.controller("MenuCtrl", ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.$state = $state;
}]);
```

In your view use an ng-href to evaluate $state object that we've now added to the $scope:

```
<div ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in menu">
            <a ng-href={{ $state.href('cf.' + item) }}>{{item}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can also you this technique for wildcard params:

```
ng-href="{{ $state.href('cf.items.item', {'item' : item} ) }}"
```

Assuming you've set up your ui-router routes properly for this.